# Anúncio na Sidebar Fixa no Topo - JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Gostei da exibição dos anúncios na sidebar desse site https://exercicios.mundoeducacao.bol.uol.com.br/exercicios-gramatica/exercicios-sobre-os-tipos-predicado-predicativo.htm

Ao rolar a página para baixo, o bloco fixa fixo por alguns pixels até que outro aparece e fica fixo até determinado pixels.

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem uma forma de fazer isso só com CSS e fica praticamente igual, não sei se é a técnica que usaram lá, mas de qq forma usando apenas CSS vc economiza uns bons Kbs e fica mais fácil a manutenção.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O principal aqui é colocar cada anuncio `.add` com `position:sticky`, e cada anuncio vai dentro de um `container` com altura de `100vh`. Como o `sticky` é relativo ao pai, e cada par tem 100% da altura do `viewport` assim que vc faz o `scroll` esse pai vai "saindo" da página, porém o `.add` permanece no lugar, mas quando o pai sai todo da página, o seu filho `.add` tb sai, dando lugar ao próximo `container` com o seu respectivo `.add`

Segue o código da imagem acima

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
  
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
main {
  display: flex;
}
section {
  height: 400vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(green, orange);
}
aside .box .add {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
aside .box .add.x {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
aside .box {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
}
aside {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section>
      avbfd
    </section>
    <aside>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="add">123</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="add x">456</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="add">789</div>
      </div>
    </aside>
</main>
```

Comment: muito bom cara, mas no link do site o ultimo fica fixo e não passa do div de rodape, em todo caso vou olhar esse css.

Comment: position: sticky; - não conhecia.

Comment: @Rod para ficar do jeito que vc quer vc pode pegar essa classe `aside .box .add { }` e deixar apenas como `aside .add { }` depois no último .add, temos 3 no exemplo. Esse último .add tire ele de dentro do .box. Tipo deixe o último .add sempre fora da div .box Ex: `<div class="box">
        <div class="add x">456</div>
      </div>
        <div class="add">789</div>` qualquer dúvida comenta ai

Comment: Aqui te ma documentação da mozilla sobre position:sticky https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position mas no Google vc encontra muito mais material sobre isso, vale uma pesquisa!

Comment: valeu hugo, no exemplo do link os blocos percorrem alguns pixels na vertical e ficam fixo por um tempo, o que aumenta o crt.

Comment: vou ler tudo com calma.

Comment: cara, estava vendo no frame pequeno, abrindo agora o executar em página grande vi que está perfeito. Vou usar. Valeu mesmo.

Comment: Se vc quiser controlar a distancia que o .add para do topo, basta na classe `aside .add` onde tem top:0, vc coloca top:20px por exemplo, ai vai para a 20px do topo

Comment: blz. tem como o ultimo deixar de ficar fixo quando atingir o rodapé, por exemplo? pra não sobrepor.

Comment: @Rod com CSS não, mas para isso acontecer o seu footer tem que ser bem alto.... O que vc pode fazer é usar algum tipo de JS/jQuery para dar um fadeOut quando ir chegando no final da página, mas de JS eu não manjo nada, não consigo te ajudar muito nessa

Comment: valeu hugo, ajudou muito.